What rises to the level of being a "a different spirit," per 2 Corinthians 11:4?
In 2 Corinthians 11, Paul speaks of his jealousy for the Corinthians church, given his early work to bring them to Christ, that they might subsequently be presented as "a pure virgin to Christ" (11:2). He then chastises them, for allowing unnamed preachers to come amongst them and deceitfully preach another Jesus, a different spirit, or a different gospel, thus drawing them away from a pure devotion to Christ. The implication is that they must reject the false teaching/teachers and return to that which Paul had proclaimed.

For if someone comes and proclaims another Jesus than the one we proclaimed, or if you receive a different spirit from the one you received, or if you accept a different gospel from the one you accepted, you put up with it readily enough. (2 Corinthians 11:4 ESV)

As modern Christians, we're pretty attentive to those groups which preach "another Jesus," such as a Jesus who isn't divine or one who isn't the exclusive Son of God. And we're definitely sensitive to the preaching of "different gospels," which offer different paths to salvation (e.g., Protestants vs. Catholics).2 Accordingly, there are numerous parachurch groups who defend their particular view of Jesus or of salvation, and who warn against the teachings of the other side. However, I rarely hear deference to the "different spirit" warning, as a basis for avoiding false teachers/teachings.
Hence, my question: How are we to understand the phrase "different spirit"? Or perhaps more specifically, what rises to the level of being a "a different spirit," per 2 Corinthians 11:4?
Presumably, the concern has to do with teachings about the Spirit which are being brought into the church. Is this passage going after false prophets, who claim private discussions with what they claim to be the Holy Spirit? Fake claimants to spiritual gifts? Or is Paul going after something else?
1The another Jesus concern was somewhat addressed here.
2The another gospel concern was somewhat addressed here, with regard to Galatians 1:6–10.

Reference to "another spirit" should swiftly remind us of the warning about the spirit of antichrist.

"Beloved, believe not every spirit, but try the spirits whether they
are of God because many false prophets are gone out into the world.
Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: every spirit that confesseth that
Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of God, And every spirit that
confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is not of God:
and this is that [spirit] of antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it
should come; and even now already it is in the world."  1John 4:1-3
A.V.

When John wrote that, Paul had earlier warned of a spirit that was against Christ, in the text in question. Truly, John was correct to say that it was already in the world! John mentioned one test - those who denied that Jesus Christ had come in the flesh. Another was that those going by the antichrist would not listen to the disciples of Christ, nor the gospel of Christ. They would be preaching a different gospel and depicting an unbiblical Christ. That was clearly what gnostic people did back then. The material, the fleshly, was obnoxious to them and they despised it. 'Their' Christ could not have been human like them; he could only have appeared to be human but was actually pure spirit. Such gnostics would not listen to the gospel preached by the apostles and disciples of Christ.
However, there were some who would agree that Jesus came in the flesh, and was fully human, clearing that hurdle. But they would (as it were) fall down at the next one. They would resist the biblical teaching that this Jesus was also fully divine - the Word (Logos) was with God in the beginning, and was God, and made everything that was made (John 1:1-3).
This illustrates that the whole gospel of Christ needs to be believed and lived out, not just bits that seem agreeable to some groups. Any group falsifying who Jesus Christ truly is has corrupted that gospel, imbibing the spirit that is against Christ.
It is a spirit of demons, who know full well that God and Christ are real (James 2:19) but they are out to get humans to either add to the biblical gospel, or take away from it. Either of those two results will suit the corrupting goals of those evil spirits.
The text in question is not so much about wrong teachings regarding the Holy Spirit (although nobody should be surprised if a group with a corrupted gospel will also have corrupted beliefs about the Holy Spirit). In his day, Paul was particularly warning the Corinthians against being corrupted by "the judaizers". Sticking to 2 Corinthians chapter 11, and knowing he had just written "we are come as far as to you also in preaching the gospel of Christ", and that he planned to preach the gospel in other regions, it is the purity of the gospel that he is defending against false teachers.
He fears that the Corinthians will be beguiled "as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty", so this is the serpentine spirit in Eden. That is the spirit Paul fears is beginning to lead the Corinthians away from what God actually said and did, in Christ. That evil spirit continues to exist to this day, and is very active getting those who profess to be Christians listening to false gospels preached by false messengers. People have always loved to have their ears ticked by speakers, and back then Paul warned Timothy:

"Now the Spirit speaketh expressly, that in the latter times some
shall depart from the faith, giving heed to seducing spirits, and
doctrines of devils; speaking lies in hypocrisy, having their
conscience seared with a hot iron; forbidding to marry, and commanding
to abstain from meats which God hath created to be received with
thanksgiving of them which believe and know the truth." 1 Tim
4:1-3) AV

Teachers back then and today in these latter times who are instruments of seducing, spirits, teach false doctrines and lies. Only a couple of examples were given there, but back in Corinthians Paul identified the judaizers in particular. He wishes they would emasculate themselves, so pernicious was their teaching that Gentile Christians should be circumcised and keep the Mosaic law. Of them he said:

"For such are false apostles, deceitful workers, transforming
themselves into the apostles of Christ [therefore, not real apostles
at all]. And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into an angel
of light. Therefore it is no great thing if his ministers also be
transformed as the ministers of righteousness; whose end shall be
according to their works." 2 Cor. 11:12-15 A.V.

There it is again - that satanic spirit infiltrating the Christian fellowship. And as Revelation foretells that evil one's supreme deception yet to be foisted on an unsuspecting world shortly before Jesus returns, we need to be more alert than ever to knowing exactly what the gospel of Christ is, believe it utterly, and not be duped by sweet but poisonous teaching. Tragically, just as the inspired word of God has never been more available, never has it been so watered down if not dismissed. The biblical ignorance of huge numbers of professed Christians will be their undoing, as those false teachers have a field day with their gullible enthusiasm for hearing what they like to hear.
This debased state is a rising up of antichrist apostates, who will gain places to such an extent that Christians will find no more place for them where they gather, and have to leave. There's a lot of leaving going on these days. They recognise the 'different spirit' because the Spirit of Christ indwells them, not the false teachers.

A good answer, and I concur that the threat comes from the spirit of antichrist. But I assume that this spirit likewise stands behind those who advance "another Jesus" and a "different gospel." We can name those who preach another Jesus and a different gospel, from whichever side of that divide we each stand on. But I'm yet trying to tease out the identities of those modern groups who preach a  "different spirit." Perhaps it is the difference between Pentecostals and Cessationists, but if we're not able to put a modern face on the culprits, then we must not truly understand the passage.

@DanMoore So true, that it's the same spirit behind all corruptions of the gospel. However, this site actively discourages identifying religious groups in a negative way. Answers (and questions) can be closed down by the Moderators if they think a group is being 'attacked' or criticized. This is not a Christian site, you see. It is not out to promote Christianity, but just to garner facts (and the more clinically cold-blooded those points are presented, the happier many folk on here seem to be!) If this comment gets wiped, I shall suspect my even saying this on a public forum is disapproved!

Indeed, which is why I've tried to be neutral in how I've presented the question. Am not trying to assess who the good vs. bad groups might be, but just the fact that our hermeneutical approach seems to be failing us in how to understand and apply this phrase, as opposed to the other phrases.

Interestingly - perhaps shockingly - the next verses in chapter 11 imply that the false teachers spreading this "different gospel" and "different spirit" are themselves apostles, seemingly greater than Paul in some ways but not in knowledge:
2 Cor. 11:5-6

I think that I am not in any way inferior to these “superapostles.” 6
Even if I am untrained in speaking, I am not so in knowledge; in every
way we have made this plain to you in all things.

Regarding the meaning of "different spirit, 1 Cor. 2 may provide a clue:

11 Among human beings, who knows what pertains to a person except the
spirit of the person that is within? Similarly, no one knows what
pertains to God except the Spirit of God. 12 We have not received the
spirit of the world but the Spirit that is from God, so that we may
understand the things freely given us by God. 13 And we speak about
them not with words taught by human wisdom, but with words taught by
the Spirit, describing spiritual realities in spiritual terms.

Here Paul contrasts the Spirit from God with the spirit of the world. The Spirit from God allows people to understand the gifts that God has given. In context, Paul refers to "God’s wisdom, mysterious, hidden, which God predetermined before the ages for our glory," namely the doctrine of salvation by faith in Jesus' atoning sacrifice.
Turning back to 2 Cor., we find this in 4:13-14:

Since, then, we have the same spirit of faith, according to what is
written, “I believed, therefore I spoke,” we too believe and therefore
speak  knowing that the one who raised the Lord Jesus will raise us
also with Jesus and place us with you in his presence.

On this basis I offer the following tentative conclusion: The "different spirit" that Paul speaks of is the "spirit of the world." This spirit does not understand the mysterious wisdom of God, namely that Jesus came to earth not as the traditional messiah but as a sacrifice for sin.  This ignorant spirit is also the spirit that promulgates the "different gospel" that some of the Corinthians have accepted, apparently taught by men of apostolic authority. It is the opposite of the "spirit of faith" (or the spirit of true faith) that Paul speaks of in 4:13.

There have been two different interpretations of 2 Cor 11:4 concerning the "different spirit", both based on the meaning of the Greek word πνεῦμα (pneuma) namely:

Different spirit, ie a demonic spirit inspiring false prophets, teachers and doctrine.  That is, the different spirit is a spirit other than the Holy Spirit, the "Spirit of truth" (John 14:17, 15:26, 16:13, 1 John 4:6, etc) who teaches about Jesus.  These different [demonic] spirit(s) teach falsehoods, etc.

Different spirit is a different attitude of mind (see BDAG and Thayer, etc).  This different attitude of mind results in one not submitting to the true apostolic teaching but replacing it with a false gospel and a false Christology.


I do not believe we need to choose between these two alternatives because either can cause the other.
Now I do not intend to document or speculate about the identity of this "different spirit" or 'different gospel", etc, because:

Eph 4:4-6 - There is one body and one Spirit, just as you were called
to one hope when you were called; one Lord, one faith, one baptism;
one God and Father of all...

By contrast, there are myriad false spirits, a myriad false gospels, a myriad false prophets, a myriad false christs, etc.

Your response is interesting, in that per option (1), the face of the "different spirit(s)" are the "false prophets" whom we can point out and denounce and guard against, along with their teachings. Hence, the warning against "different spirits" is on a par with the warning against different gospels and different Christs. But per option (2), the "different spirit" warning is more of a first cause for succumbing to the other two, which doesn't really fit the grammatical arrangement of the passage. Agreed?

@DanMoore - the different attitude, often of pride, arrogance, self-sufficiency makes a person unteachable and thus susceptible to teachings for "itching ears".
